# Assign a value from a string array to the string property of each element of a custom type array

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

Suppose I have an array of strings - `countryNames[]` - containing the names of the countries in the world:

```
string[] countryNames = { "Afghanistan" , "Albania" , "Algeria", ... }
```

I also have a class called `Country` containing these properties, among others:

```
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

My goal is to create an array of the custom type `Country`, and assign to the `Country.Name` property of each element of `Country[]` the corresponding index's string value of `countryNames[]`. I tried doing so in the following way, in the same method where I implemented the string array:

```
Country[] countries = new Country[193];
for (int i = 0; i < 193; i++)
{
    countries[i].Name = countryNames[i];
}
return countries;
```

The `countries[i].Name` however, causes a `NullReferenceException` . I can't see where the problem is though, as the property `Country.Name` is a string. Are there any complications when arrays and properties are mixed together?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Only initialization of array will not suffice. You have to create country objects before entering the for loop and add them in array. Then you can assign value to Name property of each country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you get a `NullReferenceException` is that when you initialize an array of object it doesn't initialize the items within it. Meaning that when you access `countries[i].Name` that object doesn't exist, and then `.Name` throws the exception.

So you need to initialize it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 193; i++)
{
    countries[i] = new Country { Name = countryNames[i] };
}
```

A better way that using a for loop is using a `foreach`:

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
foreach(var countryName in countryNames
{
    countries.Add(new Country { Name = countryName });
}
```

And then from the foreach you can leap to linq:

```
string[] countryNames = { "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria" };
var countried = countryNames.Select(item => new Country { Name = item });
```

Comment: Thanks. The Linq method is even better as it does the job in a single line of code!

Answer (score 2):

You should make a new `Country` first:

```
Country[] countries = new Country[193];

for (int i = 0; i < 193; i++)
{
    countries[i] = new Country();
    countries[i].Name = countryNames[i];
}

return countries;
```

By doing:

```
Country[] countries = new Country[193];
```

You are only reserving space for the array, the individual elements are initialized to `null`